# Reader is empty

Tags: c#, sql, odbc, datareader

I have a data reader that gets empty results but I don't get why?

My connection state is open, i tested my query in my DB, it returns values but there my `reader.read()` just get skipped

```
OdbcDataReader Reader;
string mond = "select fir_mdnt from safir JOIN safirbpv ON firbpv_fir = fir_fir where firbpv_ibnr = '" + _cb_Compte.SelectedItem + "' group by fir_mdnt;";
OdbcCommand mondant = new OdbcCommand(mond, InfoConnexion);

InfoConnexion.Open();
Reader = mondant.ExecuteReader();
while (Reader.Read())
{
    MessageBox.Show(Reader.ToString());
}
InfoConnexion.Close();
```

Comment: is you sql statement returning rows?. Seems sql query doesn't return  any row matching with  "_cb_Compte.SelectedItem "

Comment: Check for the _cb_Compte.SelectedItem value, Extract the select query and check in database if any value is returned or not. This will confirm whether the issue is with the .NET code or there is no record in database with such filter value.

Comment: First and foremost, **[USE PARAMETERISED QUERIES](http://bobby-tables.com/)**, sorry to yell, but this is so important, not just for security, but for query plan re-use, and preventing possible data truncation and conversion errors. Have you tried debugging to see the exact query being issued by the command?

Comment: My query looks like this when i use the step by step debug :

select fir_mdnt from safir JOIN safirbpv ON firbpv_fir = fir_fir where firbpv_ibnr = 'CH1200767000A07116162' group by fir_mdnt;

when i try it in my DB it returns what i want, an int.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "skipped"? Does `Reader.Read()` return false or do you mean the line is never even executed? If the latter then you have thrown an exception that you are not catching anywhere.

Comment: @Crowcoder no exception is thrown, the line is not even executed, my `Reader` is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, *brush up* the routine and put a *break point* on `using (OdbcDataReader reader = mondant.ExecuteReader()) {`

The code cleared

```
//DONE: make SQL readable
//DONE: make SQL parametrized (ODBC doesn't support named parameters, but ?)
string sql = 
    @"select fir_mdnt 
        from safir join 
             safirbpv on firbpv_fir = fir_fir 
       where firbpv_ibnr = ?
    group by fir_mdnt";

//DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
//DONE: do not share the connection but create a new one
using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(connectionStringHere)) {
  con.Open();

  //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
  using(OdbcCommand mondant = new OdbcCommand(sql, con)) {
    //TODO: check the actual parameter type and value
    //TODO: you may want to add Trim: _cb_Compte.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim() 
    mondant.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("", OdbcType.Text) 
      {Value = _cb_Compte.SelectedItem}); 

    //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
    //TODO: put a break point here
    using (OdbcDataReader reader = mondant.ExecuteReader()) {
      while (reader.Read()) {
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(reader[0]));
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Then you have to *debug*

- Run the code.
- Stop on the *break point*.
- Check `sql`, parameter (its value).
- Check `reader.HasRows` value.
- Execute the query at any kind of RDMBS editor: do you have any records returned?

Comment: I cleaned my code like you said, i also deleted any space in my `_cb_Compte.SelectedItem` and it works now.

Thank you